# Elixir: reduce over list where the reducer function takes in the subset of the list iterated over so far as a parameter

Tags: elixir, reduce

The function in `Enum.reduce` is invoked with the next element and the accumulator. I want this but instead, of the next element, the reducer should take in the subset of the list iterated over so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accumulator in [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) might be whatever, so one might collect already visited elements. Somewhat like below should work (untested).

```elixir
[1, 2, 3]
|> Enum.reduce({[], 0}, fn e, {head, acc} ->
  head = head ++ [e]
  acc = acc + Enum.sum(head)
  {head, acc}
end)
|> elem(1)
#⇒ 10
```

The result should be `10` because we add up `1` three times, `2` two times, and `3` one time.